# JOIN using MIN() where MIN() is greater than value on left side of join

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do some conversion analysis on a load of existing data that we have in a (few) SQL database.

The data strucutre itself is very simple. It's just a list of actors (think user_id) and a name of something they did. It looks like this (there's other data, but that will not be used in this query):

```
CREATE TABLE views(
    project_id integer not null,
    name varchar(128) not null,
    datetime timestamp not null,
    actor varchar(256) not null
)
```

The goal is standard conversion analysis stuff. Number of people who did action A, then did B, C, D, E etc, and the average time between steps.

For clarity, the funnel steps dictate order, but not exclusivity. For example, a funnel looking for names A, B, C should include an actor who's sequence was B, A, B, D, C (as that contains an A, then later a B, then later a C, even though there are steps in between).

Currently I am querying this table using the following (Each join represents the next step in the conversion funnel):

```
SELECT count(actor), count(span2), avg(span2), count(span3), avg(span3), count(span4), avg(span4), count(span5), avg (span5)
FROM
(
    SELECT e1.actor, 
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(e1.datetime), MIN(e2.datetime)) AS span2,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(e2.datetime), MIN(e3.datetime)) AS span3,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(e3.datetime), MIN(e4.datetime)) AS span4,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(e4.datetime), MIN(e5.datetime)) AS span5
    FROM views AS e1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT actor, MIN(datetime) as datetime FROM views WHERE name = 'Action 2' group by actor) as e2 ON e1.actor = e2.actor AND e2.datetime > e1.datetime
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT actor, MIN(datetime) as datetime FROM views WHERE name = 'Action 3' group by actor) as e3 ON e1.actor = e3.actor AND e3.datetime > e2.datetime
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT actor, MIN(datetime) as datetime FROM views WHERE name = 'Action 4' group by actor) as e4 ON e1.actor = e4.actor AND e4.datetime > e3.datetime
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT actor, MIN(datetime) as datetime FROM views WHERE name = 'Action 5' group by actor) as e5 ON e1.actor = e5.actor AND e5.datetime > e4.datetime
    WHERE e1.project_id = 1 and e1.name = 'Action 1'
    GROUP BY e1.actor
) AS aggregates
```

This is quite fast on the data set (<1s on 10M rows). The problem is that it is not actually the correct result. The sub selected joins are asking for MIN(datetime) each time. If an actor sequence happens in the order B, A, B this will not be counted as MIN(A) is greater than MIN(B).

Given a set of actors, who have performed a list of views, I need to check each actor to see if they have performed view A, then later view B, then later view C, regardless of any steps they did in the middle. B, A, B, C qualifies, A, B, B, C qualifies, A, B, Z, C qualifies, A, Z, C does not

To query this "properly" I can remove the MIN(datetime) in the sub joins, and do the MIN() outside the join. This however takes an extremely long time as each row is then joined multiple times for each funnel step (steps are often repeated out of order). The cross product in this case is huge - 21 quadrillion rows says the query planner! (21,666,755,307,950,608). That's obviously no longer a sub 1 second query.

What I want do achieve is a join where the join happens on the MIN value, but where the MIN value is the "MIN value greater than the previous join step". I.e. so for step A to B, the B.datetime is the single MIN B.datetime that is still greater than A.datetime. Something like (not valid SQL!):

```
.... 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT actor, datetime FROM views WHERE name = 'Action 2') as e2 
ON e1.actor = e2.actor AND e2.datetime > e1.datetime HAVING MIN(e.datetime)
....
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Functions specific to either MySQL or PostgreSQL are fine if suitable.

Comment: If this is really a funnel, how can you go from "B" to "A"?  Can you give some examples of the outlier paths and how the data should be counted?

Comment: As mentioned, solutions valid in either. It's valid MySQL if DATEDIFF is changed to TIMESTAMPDIFF instead. Rest of query is identical. It was actually written in MySQL to start. There is similar data in both DBs so I'm happy for a valid solution in either.

Comment: Sounds quite easy using Postgres' `lag()` function

Comment: Sure. If you have a path A, B, C, but step B can also be a standalone action, or shared with another process, then you have the case where an actor can have sequence B, A, B, C. MIN(B) then occurs before MIN(A).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest just looking at all transition times.  Here is how you can do this in SQL:

```
SELECT prevName, name, count(*) as NumTransitions,
       avg(DATEDIFF(SECOND, "datetime", prevdatetime))
FROM (SELECT e1.actor, "datetime", name,
             lag(name) over (partition by actor order by "datetime") as prevName,
             lag("datetime") over (partition by actor order by "datetime") as prevDateTime
      FROM views AS e1
      WHERE e1.project_id = 1 
     ) t
GROUP BY prevName, name;
```

If you want the number of "actors" for each transition, you can add `count(distinct actor)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful although it doesn't get the results I need (or I don't think it does anyway). Given example sequence B, A, B, D, C, that should be counted by funnel A, B, C. I can't get that from this query. Intermediate steps are skipped (which I probably should have put in the question with hind sight). I do however need to do  a reverse funnel too (Given C, what action happens before) and LAG/LEAD work great in that case, so at least I can still use this answer for that instead!

Comment: @AndySavage . . . You seem to have a major problem with your path analysis.  You describe something as a funnel that goes every which way.  I think you need to take a step back, look at the actual sequences in the data, and then understand what is happening.  It sounds like you are trying to fit user behavior in some "theoretical" set of transitions, and the users simply are not cooperating.

Comment: I think my problem lies in the clarity of my explanation rather than the path. I don't meant it to sound "every which way". Given a set of actors, who have performed a list of views, I need to check each actor to see if they have performed view A, then later view B, then later view C, regardless of any steps they did in the middle. B, A, B, C qualifies, A, B, B, C qualifies, A, B, Z, C qualifies, A, Z, C does not. Was that unclear in my question? I will alter if so. It's hard for me to see because I know what I mean!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I think it is the sql you're using for the inline views that are to blame.

Please try the below. If not could you post some example data and desired results?

```
SELECT count(actor), count(span2), avg(span2), count(span3), avg(span3), count(span4), avg(span4), count(span5), avg (span5)
FROM
(
    SELECT e1.actor, 
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(e1.datetime), MIN(e2.datetime)) AS span2,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(e2.datetime), MIN(e3.datetime)) AS span3,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(e3.datetime), MIN(e4.datetime)) AS span4,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(e4.datetime), MIN(e5.datetime)) AS span5
FROM views as e1, views as e2, views as e3, views as e4, views as e5
where e1.actor = e2.actor and e1.actor = e3.actor and e1.actor = e4.actor and e1.actor = e5.actor
  and e2.datetime = (select min(x.datetime) from views x where x.name = 'Action 2' and x.actor = e2.actor and x.datetime > e1.datetime)
  and e3.datetime = (select min(x.datetime) from views x where x.name = 'Action 3' and x.actor = e3.actor and x.datetime > e2.datetime)
  and e4.datetime = (select min(x.datetime) from views x where x.name = 'Action 4' and x.actor = e4.actor and x.datetime > e3.datetime)
  and e5.datetime = (select min(x.datetime) from views x where x.name = 'Action 5' and x.actor = e5.actor and x.datetime > e4.datetime)
  and e1.project_id = 1 and e1.name = 'Action 1'
    GROUP BY e1.actor
) AS aggregates
```